# C: Separate array of strings into single words

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, matrix

I have an array that is filled with sentences, my array is declared like this

```
char *arraystr[size];
```

And is filled by a strtok that separates a string into different sentences and fills it.

```
arraystr[0]="In which class are you studying";

arraystr[1]="I am in Eighth Standard";
```

I want to separate the sentences word by word, and store it in an array or a matrix. like this:

```
single_words[0]="In"

single_words[1]="which"

single_words[2]="class"

//...
```

I have done it, but I'm running into a crash when there is nothing more to separate, I guess it doesn't know when to stop.

My code:

```
void str_array_line(char str[],int *size,char* arraystr[])
{
    char *token = strtok(str, "?.!\n");
    int i=0;
    while(token!=NULL)
    {
        arraystr[i] = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
        strcpy(arraystr[i], token);
        //printf("Array[%d][%s]\n",i, arraystr[i]);
        token = strtok(NULL, "?.!\n");
        i++;
        *size=i;
    }
}
void array_single_words(char *arraystr[],char* single_words[])
{
    int i=0,j=0;
    for(j=0;j<strlen(arraystr[j]);j++)
    {
        char *token = strtok(arraystr[j], " \t");
        while(token!=NULL)
        {
            single_words[i] = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);;
            strcpy(single_words[i], token);
            printf("Array[%d][%s]\n",i, single_words[i]);
            token = strtok(NULL, " \t");
            i++;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char str[]="In which class are you studying?Sandhiya : I am in Eighth Standard. What about you?Saniya : I am in Ninth Standard\nSandhiya : Do you come to school by bus?\nSaniya : Yes. I travel by bus. I have to catch Route No 24 bus.\nSandhiya : It has passed on just 15 minutes before.";
    int size=sizeof(str);
    int i=0;
    char *arraystr[size];
    str_array_line(str,&size,arraystr);
    printf("Size: %d\n",size);
    char *single_words[255];
    array_single_words(arraystr,single_words);
}
```

Comment: Just like you used `strtok` to separate text into sentences, you can use it to separate sentences into words. I suggest you try it and ask a specific question about any problem you run into, because people here won't solve your homework for you.

Comment: Welcome to SO ! to get the most of SO please show what you have tried and what was the result for each output

Comment: i have added the code

Comment: Why do these two functions return `void` ? They have so much to say...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple of issues with your code. In `array_single_words`, you are iterating over all the sentences. So the `j` loop has to run over the number of sentences in the `arraystr[]` array.

Instead of

```
for(j=0;j<strlen(arraystr[j]);j++)
```

you should write

```
for(j=0;j<size;j++)
```

for a quick fix, because in the earlier run of `str_array_line` you set `size` to the number of elements in the array.

That being said, the first `malloc` of the `arraystr` array should not be size `size`, and the way you are re-using the same variable to mean different things is questionable and will confuse yourself. Also, think about not returning the array size as a side effect in a function parameter.

Comment: i returned the number of elements in the array so i could print in main the entire array of sentences. thank you, you stopped the crashing problem.